# Creating dynamic scope inside ngIf

Tags: angularjs

I've checked all the solutions in here, but couldn't find one that worked for me

Basically i'm using ngIf inside ngRepeat, therefore, the conditions for triggering the ngIf will be different based on the ID of each block, like below

```
<div ng-if="doSomething_ID1"><div>
<div ng-if="doSomething_ID2"><div>
<div ng-if="doSomething_ID3"><div>
<div ng-if="doSomething_ID4"><div>
```

If i were to write the above inside ngRepeat statement, is this the correct way? Because i tried below but it didn't work for me

```
<div ng-repeat="this in these">
    <div ng-if="'doSomething_'+ this.id"><div>
<div>
```

Also if i were to pass value from the controller to the dynamic scopes above, can i do something like this?

```
for (var i=0; i<these.length; i++){
    $scope["doSomething_" + these[i].id] = someValueHere;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: From <div ng-if="'doSomething_'+ this.id"><div> your ng-if will "always" evaluate to "true" since it has a non-empty string.

Comment: @RaviTeja you mean that underscore? So will 'doSomething'+this.id works? Sorry because i'm not that familiar handling expressions/statements inside directive for Angular.

Comment: No. I mean by  'doSomething'+this.id. Even if id gets somehow undefined you will always have a 'doSomething' which is a non-empty string. So, non-empty string always evaluate to true.

Comment: Can you take a look at http://plnkr.co/edit/wp3Ozqt1NgL1VVoeT3ns?p=preview and let me know what exactly is your requirement.

Comment: `ng-if` should contain an `expression` which should either evaluate to `true` or `false`. You are passing a `string` and the is no comparision which will always evaluate to `true`. You might want to consider changing your `ng-if` to something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/mznagsgu/2/). Just something to get you started.

Comment: Your code is flawed by design. You shouldn't use calculated variable names, but rather define names and use those throughout the application. If you need to loop over a set of values, create a new array with only these values and loop without conditions in the template.

Comment: Rule of a thumb for help requests: state the problem first, then your attempt. Do not ask for a fix of your half-baked solution because the idea might be not suitable for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to loop over a set of values, create a new array with only these values and loop without conditions in the template. Conditions in the template should be only used for view-related things, not for business logic. E.g.: showing a comments box if a post has any comments; showing a log-out button when the current user is logged in.

Instead of adding `doSomething_IDX` to the scope, add an array of objects to the scope. In that array put all items you want to show in the template.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.itemlist">
    item id: {{ item.id }}
<div>
```

---

In your controller:

```
this.itemlist = []
for (var i=0; i<these.length; i++) {
    var item = these[i];
    // filter list here
    if (meetsCondition(item)) {
        this.itemlist.push(these[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The ngIf is indeed there for view related thing. The idea here is to display a list of item, in which each item in the list will have 2 modes, display or edit mode, depending on which button is pressed on each of the item. I'm using ngIf here to switch from display to edit view or vice versa for each item, but the problem i'm facing here is that, when i used generic expressions to do the switching, it will affect all the items in the list, which is why i planned to create more specific scope for each item, so that it will call for that specific scope only and change the display.

Comment: How about creating an abstract component controller and make all distinct component controllers inherit from it? In that abstract component you put all the logic required for the state switching. If you want multiple inputs of the same type in a template, you simply use the component multiple times.